# After a comment is posted and I try to like it, ajax lags and doesn't work immediately

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I have a comment liking system in a Django website I'm building, where when a comment is liked, an ajax function is called. However, I've found that right after I post a comment, and try to like my own comment, the request.is_ajax() == FALSE instead of TRUE like it normally is. After a few minutes, and I reload it, the like button works fine. Is there an explanation for this, or has anyone encountered something similar? What was your solution? I'll put my code underneath in case it's relevant, but it's strange to me because it normally works well, it's only when I try to like a comment I just posted that it glitches out.

AJAX:

```
$('#comment-form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                $('.comments-section').html(response['form']);
                $('.reply-link').click(function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $(this).parents('.parent-comment').next('.replies').fadeToggle();
                })
                $('textarea').val('');
                console.log('work')
            },
            error: function(rs, e) {console.log(rs.responseText)}
        })
    })
```

VIEWS.PY:

```
@never_cache
@login_required(login_url='login')
def change_comment_like(request, pk):
    comment = Comment.objects.get(pk=pk)
    print(comment)
    print(request.method)
    print(request.is_ajax())
    if request.method=='POST' and request.is_ajax():
        print('work')
        user = request.user
        liked = False
        if user in comment.likes.all():
            comment.likes.remove(user)
        else:
            comment.likes.add(user)
            liked = True
        comment.save()
        print(comment)
        return JsonResponse({'liked': liked})
    return redirect('post_detail', pk=comment.post.pk)
```

Comment: Is your javascript wrapped in a $(window).on('load', function() {...})?

Comment: Yes, it is - Or rather $(document).ready(function() {})